# HIVE SQL Calculation

Tags: hive

I need to the answer in 5 decimal places in HIVE (store_ratio need to be in 5 decimal.  Source table has total_order value.

```sql
Select Store_number, order_number, (1/total_orders) as store_ratio
From Master_Store_order
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `round` function which allows you tp specify the number of decimal places

```sql
Select Store_number, order_number, ROUND(1/total_orders,5) as store_ratio From Master_Store_order
```

Comment: @ashpatel Please mark this as the answer so that other S/O users may find it helpful.